# Save the PDF and email as well

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django-rest-framework, html-email, nodemailer

Email the Template saved as pdf.

I have been working on react js app, where i need two things, SAVE PDF or EMAIL INVOICE.I have done SAVE PDF by using windows.print(),now I need to email it user can click directly on email pdf and it should be email to the user, i have checked a lot but there were different appoarches,I want to email it through react js without going to the backend (Django Rest) can it be done through react js only?Here's my simple login to print or save in pdf form, where I also want if user clicks email pdf button it should be emailed to him in pdf form

```
           <div className="p-y-lg">
              <a className="btn btn-success btn-sm" href="javascript:window.print()">
                    <span className="icon icon-print icon-lg icon-fw">
                    </span>
                    Print
              </a>
            </div>
```

What can I do in above approach so I can able to email the above pdf to the user directly.I have user email stored,so any simple approach?

Comment: PDF as attachment or content of PDF as email body?

Comment: I want to send PDF file

Answer (score 0):

You can't send an email directly with javascript.

You can, however, open the user's mail client:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com');
```

There are also some parameters to pre-fill the subject and the body:

```
window.open('mailto:test@example.com?subject=subject&body=body');
```

Comment: Looks like it will work for me, can I pass files parameters also like subject and body?